# Pydev and Eclipse Marketplace - Eclipse e4

Tags: eclipse, pydev, e4

I am still try to make that my e4 rcp open the Pydev perspective (made with 3.x version).

If i download a new version of eclipse (ex: Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers, version: Oxygen), and trough  the option of install new software or Marketpace add the pydev without any issue and i can use all pydev, how it works?

Comment: pydev uses 3.x compatibility mode so it won't run as part of a pure e4 RCP which doesn't contain the code for 3.x compatibility mode.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, so the compatibility mode have to be in the 3.x part? if a develop a plugin in 3.x can i added later as a feature to e4 pure? Do you have a good explanation or example how use compatibility mode, i could't find good info. Thanks.

Comment: 3.x compatibilty mode means including all the `org.eclipse.ui.xxxx` plugins etc. which aren't in a pure e4 app. You use the old style Eclipse 3.x RCP development for that. Plugins using any 3.x compatibility mode code can't be added to a pure e4 RCP as they use APIs and extension points which aren't present.

Comment: You can use some e4 features when developing an old style 3.x RCP.

Comment: Ok, so if not possible to add an 3.x as feature to e4.

Comment: Ok, so if not possible to add an 3.x as feature to e4. my best approach was use this example [link](https://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/),  from that as base i can open the pydev perspective using 3.x commands but is a mess, appears bug for toolbar of Application.e4xmi the toolbar have to be added from plugin.xml, etc. I will keep with searching.

Comment: So how the new Eclipse IDE allow add the Pydev if is not possible add using features or extending? Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse IDE is a 3.x compatibilty mode RCP

Comment: Ok, so basically if i want use both i need an 3.x plugin development and add the necessary to use e4 characteristic? Thanks.